# JQuery - Loading HTML into textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql-real-escape-string

Ok, I have this php variable:

```
<?php
$htmlstring = '<p>This is a test email<br /><br /><br /></p>
<p><span style="color: #808080; font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif;"><strong>Some Text here with an apostophe or image: <br /><img title="Test Img" src="http://somefakeurl.com/img/somefakeimg.gif" alt="test img" width="112" height="59" />';
?>
```

And I have this below it on my main.php

```
<textarea name="testload" id="testload"></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#testload").val('<?=$htmlstring;?>');

});
```

This won't display.
However, if I change it to the code below, it'll display:

```
 $("#testload").val('<?=mysql_real_escape_string($htmlstring);?>');
```

I feel like I'm bandaiding the process, but perhaps it's fine?
(also, I have plans to dynamically load other html into the same textarea, and this is just for testing a single html string)

Comment: You're aware that you have the `id` `testload` in your HTML and `testpoo` in your JS? Otherwise, why are you not just echoing the text at the relevant point in the HTML, since it's ready when the page is rendered?

Comment: Fixed, yes you were right.  `testpoo` was on my box, and didn't want to show that on here. BUT!  the cats out of the bag now. Sooooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape it for SQL, but for javascript.

```
$("#testload").val(<?= json_encode($htmlstring);?>);
```

Comment: @IMSoP `json_encode`, when called with a string argument, escapes a string for javascript AND json. Just like it would result in valid javascript when called with an array or object.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you're quite right - if you know the input is a string, serializing and encoding are very nearly equivalent (with the difference that serializing will also add quotes around the whole thing).

Comment: @IMSoP yeah, I removed the quotes because you don't manually need to add them

Comment: Learned something new here.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

If there is no reason as to why you are loading this via jQuery why don't you just do:

```
<textarea name="testload" id="testload">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($htmlstring); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I have other intentions of loading more html dynamically.